# Python overloading non-existent operator works, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, operators, overloading

While messing around with overloading operators and namedtuples, I've stumbled on some weird behavior which works, for some reason or another:

https://repl.it/repls/RemorsefulFlawlessAfricanwildcat

```
import collections, math

Point = collections.namedtuple("Point", ["x", "y"])
Point.__floor__ = lambda self: Point(int(math.floor(self.x)), int(math.floor(self.y)))
print(math.floor(Point(1.4, -5.9)))
#prints: Point(x=1, y=-6)
```

Does anyone have any insight into this? Why does it work?
If I remove the `Point.__floor__` line, it doesn't work.

---

Did the math package define a `__floor__` operator somewhere?
OR
Does Python parse `Point.__XXX__` to extract `XXX` and compare with the name of the thing (function/operator) that acts on the argument?

I'm confused, probably because I don't know how exactly these things work deep down.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> `math.floor(x)`
>
> Return the floor of `x`, the largest integer less than or equal to x. **If x is not a float, delegates to `x.__floor__()`**, which should return an Integral value.

Comment: Thanks! I found it myself just before I read your answer. I looked in https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model , but couldn't find it. Later found it where you linked. In hindsight, I should have checked math.floor documentation, but I thought all __ XXX __ are listed in the datamodel.html page.